# How to Integrate this expression?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

All the parameters ($r, b,$ and $q$) are real and positive. Is it possible to do the below integration?

```
 2*b^2*Integrate[r^2*(-1 - E^(ProductLog[q^2/(b^2*r^4)]/2)*
 (-1 + ProductLog[q^2/(b^2*r^4)])), r]
```

It seems that changing the variables may be useful. For example, assuming $q^2/(b^2 r^4)=X$ could be helpful, however, the answer is complicated. Is there any neat method?

Answer (score 1):

Your proposed substitution works well.

```
f = 2 b^2 r^2*(-1 - 
E^(ProductLog[q^2/(b^2*r^4)]/2)*(-1 + ProductLog[q^2/(b^2*r^4)]))

sol = Solve[Join[th = Thread[{b, q, r, x} > 0], {q^2/(b^2 r^4) == x}],
 r, Reals] // ToRadicals // Simplify[#, th] &

(*   {{r -> -(Sqrt[(q/b)]/x^(1/4))}}   *)
```

Unfortunately `ToRadicals`  makes a sign error here, but with the original result `Root[-q^2 + b^2 x #1^4 &, 2]`  Integrate doesn't work.

```
{{r -> -(Sqrt[(q/b)]/x^(1/4))}} /. {b -> 1, q -> 1, x -> 2} // N

(*   {{r -> -0.840896}}   *)

Root[-q^2 + b^2 x #1^4 &, 2] /. {b -> 1, q -> 1, x -> 2} // N

(*   0.840896   *)

drdx = D[-r /. sol[[1]], x]

f2 = f*drdx /. sol[[1]]

intx[x_, b_, q_] = Integrate[f2, x] // FullSimplify[#, th] &

(*   -((2 Sqrt[b] q^(
3/2) (1 + 
ExpIntegralE[3/4, ProductLog[x]/4] (x^3 ProductLog[x])^(1/4) + 
E^(ProductLog[x]/2) (-1 + 3 ProductLog[x])))/(3 x^(3/4)))   *)

intr[r_, b_, q_] = 
  intx[x, b, q] /. x -> q^2/(b^2 r^4) // FullSimplify[#, th] &

(*   1/3 (-2 b^2 r^3 - 
 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[b q^3] Gamma[1/4, 1/4 ProductLog[q^2/(b^2 r^4)]] + (
 2 b q r (1 - 3 ProductLog[q^2/(b^2 r^4)]))/Sqrt[
 ProductLog[q^2/(b^2 r^4)]])   *)
```

Test

```
intr[10, 1, 1] - Limit[intr[r, 1, 1], r -> 0, Direction -> -1] // N

(*   -3.31826   *)

NIntegrate[
 2*b^2*r^2*(-1 - 
 E^(ProductLog[q^2/(b^2*r^4)]/2)*(-1 + 
    ProductLog[q^2/(b^2*r^4)])) /. {b -> 1, q -> 1}, {r, 0, 10}]

(*   -3.31826   *)

D[intr[r, b, q], r] - f // FullSimplify[#, th] &

(*   0   *)
```